# java.lang.IllegalStateException getString in Retrofit2 Callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit2

I'm getting this error in a Retrofit2 onResponse `java.lang.IllegalStateException`
while trying to get the `SharePreferences` to save some values in a Fragment.

```
MyApi myApi = retrofit.create(myApi.class);
Call<MyExpectedResponse> myApiCall = myApi.getThoseValues("Some dummy parameters");

myApiCall.enqueue(new Callback<MyExpectedResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyExpectedResponse> call, Response<MyExpectedResponse> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){

            MyExpectedResponse myExpectedResponse = response.body();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(
                getString(R.string.preferences_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            //the line avobe is where the exceptions is said to be thrown

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("stored_data", myExpectedResponse.returnMeSomeString());
            editor.apply();

        } else {
          showAnErrorDialog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<TokenError> call, Throwable t) {
        showAnotherErrorDialog();
    }
});}
```

This stacktrace also shows a Retrofit exception that emulates a request cancelation

**ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68**

```
// Emulate OkHttp's behavior of throwing/delivering an IOException on cancellation.
callback.onFailure(ExecutorCallbackCall.this, new IOException("Canceled"));
```

However there is no exception about a non-attached fragment, network/socket timeout.
Also tried to emulate the error sending the app to the background and removing/adding activities to make the Fragment's activity reach onPause and onStop.
I have canceled the request on purpose and it doesn't happen.
The exception is happening randomly.
I havent found the exact way to throw the error on purpose.

Is there any specific error on how I am accessing the SharedPreferences?
Should I wrap the preferences code inside an `isAdded()` condition?